# Batch distribution fitting using Tidyverse and fitdistrplus

Tags: r, tidyverse, fitdistrplus

I have a dataset that is as follows (10,000+ Rows):

| P_ID | SNUM | RNUM | X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_233 | 10 | 2 | 40.31 |
| ID_233 | 10 | 3 | 23.21 |
| ID_234 | 12 | 5 | 11.00 |
| ID_234 | 12 | 6 | 0.31 |
| ID_234 | 13 | 1 | 0.00 |
| ID_235 | 10 | 2 | 66.23 |

From this dataset, I want to fit each distinct `P_ID` to a Gamma distribution (ignoring the testing of how well the sampled data fits the distribution)

Using the `fitdistrplus` package, I can achieve this by extracting the `X` for an individual `P_ID` into a vector and then run it through  `fw <- fitdist(data,"gamma")` and then extract the `shape` and `rate` descriptive variables out, but this is all very manual.

I would like to find a method using tidyverse to go from the data frame above to:

| P_ID | Distrib | G_Shape | G_Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_233 | Gamma | 1.21557116 | 0.09206639 |
| ID_234 | Gamma | 3.23234542 | 0.34566432 |
| ID_235 | Gamma | 2.34555553 | 0.92344521 |

How would i achieve this with Tidyverse and Pipes and not doing a succession of for loops?

Comment: How do you extract `shape` and `rate` descriptive variables out of `fw` ?

Comment: `fw$estimate['shape']` and `fw$estmate['rate']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply  `fitdist` for every individual using `group_by` and extract `shape` and `rate` values out of each model.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(fitdistrplus)

data %>%
  group_by(P_ID) %>%
  summarise(model = list(fitdist(X, "gamma"))) %>%
  mutate(G_Shape = map_dbl(model, pluck, 'estimate', 'shape'),
         G_rate =  map_dbl(model, pluck, 'estimate', 'rate')) -> result

result
```